# Add permutation outcomes into a string and break line between them

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

I want to write a list of permutations, and between each permutation, break the line so I don't end up with the giant mess that I usually get of parens and blocks, ect.

How might I do this?

Furthermore, how would I add together the permutations to create one string per outcome?
My code:

```
import itertools
print(list(itertools.permutations(["an","de","si","ta"],4)))
```

Ideally, i would like it print something like this:

```
andesita 
tasidean
```

Instead of:

```
[('an', 'de', 'si', 'ta'), ('an', 'de', 'ta', 'si'), ('an', 'si', 'de', 'ta'), ('an', 'si', 'ta', 'de'), ('an', 'ta', 'de', 'si'), ('an', 'ta', 'si', 'de'), ('de', 'an', 'si', 'ta'), ('de', 'an', 'ta', 'si'), ('de', 'si', 'an', 'ta'), ('de', 'si', 'ta', 'an'), ('de', 'ta', 'an', 'si'), ('de', 'ta', 'si', 'an'), ('si', 'an', 'de', 'ta'), ('si', 'an', 'ta', 'de'), ('si', 'de', 'an', 'ta'), ('si', 'de', 'ta', 'an'), ('si', 'ta', 'an', 'de'), ('si', 'ta', 'de', 'an'), ('ta', 'an', 'de', 'si'), ('ta', 'an', 'si', 'de'), ('ta', 'de', 'an', 'si'), ('ta', 'de', 'si', 'an'), ('ta', 'si', 'an', 'de'), ('ta', 'si', 'de', 'an')]
```

Comment: Your code and output don't match

Comment: Fixed it. Ty for noticing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the `itertools.permutations()` results and use `str.join()` to create one string from each:

```
for combo in itertools.permutations(["an", "de", "si", "ta"], 4):
    print(''.join(combo))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for combo in itertools.permutations(["an", "de", "si", "ta"], 4):
...     print(''.join(combo))
...
andesita
andetasi
ansideta
ansitade
antadesi
antaside
deansita
deantasi
desianta
desitaan
detaansi
detasian
siandeta
siantade
sideanta
sidetaan
sitaande
sitadean
taandesi
taanside
tadeansi
tadesian
tasiande
tasidean
```

Comment: Perfect output!! Thanks